# Fibonacci Algorithm in Java

Tags: java, fibonacci

I'm trying to solve a homework problem for an algorithms class and I keep getting an out of bounds index array for the code I've written below. I've been trying to play around with it in Python since I'm pretty comfortable with that, but I seem to be getting a similar exception. Can anyone give me a hint as to where I'm going wrong with this?

```java
public class Fibonacci1 {
    public static long F(int N) {
        long a[]  = new long [100];
        a[0] = 0; /*sets up first 2 digits in the sequence*/
        a[1] = 1;
        if (N<2) {   
            return N;
        }
        a[N] = a[N-1] + a[N-2]; /*appends F num for next number in the list*/
        N++; 
        return a[N]; /*should return the last number*/
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int N = 0; N<100; N++)
            StdOut.println(N+" " + F(N));
    }
}
```

Comment: http://blog.paulvargas.org/numeros-fibonacci/

Comment: and the algorithm is wrong. you'd better google and find a correct one

Comment: @gefei, I was going to point out the same, but you were faster!

Comment: One of the many resources: [Fibonacci numbers (Java)](http://en.literateprograms.org/Fibonacci_numbers_%28Java%29)

Comment: You don't need an array. You can calculate it iteratively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code needs to changed a bit.  Your not getting the right sequence printed out because the array is a local variable and should be a static variable.  Also the n++ should be removed.  The code below is not pretty but it works.

```
public class Fibonacci1 {
    static long a[] = new long[100];

    public static long F(int N) {
        a[0] = 0; /* sets up first 2 digits in the sequence */
        a[1] = 1;
        if (N < 2) {
            return N;
        }
        a[N] = a[N - 1] + a[N - 2]; /* appends F num for next number in the list */
        return a[N]; /* should return the last number */
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int N = 0; N < 100; N++)
            System.out.println(N + " " + F(N));
        }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that did it. Sorry to bother the SO community with a Fib question, I really tried to spend some time on this before I asked anyone. I know programmers hate rudimentary questions, especially Fib!

Comment: No problem.  We have all been there before staring at our code.  Good luck.

Answer (score 10):

when `N == 99`, you do an `N++` in method F, then you call return `a[N]`, which means return `a[100]`

Comment: To make this clearer: An array that can hold 100 elements has indexes 0 to 99, so index 100 is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the N++ statement from the F-Function.